# How to mimic a HTTP POST request?

Tags: network, http

I want to mimic a HTTP POST request that I intercepted and have raw on a file, what would be the best way to send it and be certain that I sent exactly the same request?

example file: (private data redacted obviously)

```
POST /mobile/testAPN.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
User-Agent: [REDACTED]
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
X-APP_PROFILE: 8
X-Protocol: 2
X-VAYO-LANG: he
X-IMEI: [REDACTED]
X-Handset_Platform: ANDROID
X-IMSI: [REDACTED]    
X-PID: [REDACTED]    
X-VAYO-ID: 1    
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8    
Content-Length: 3    
Host: [REDACTED]    

n=v
```

Comment: We don't know what your raw file looks like so there's no way for us to tell you exactly what to do. Postman is a good tool to send custom requests to a given URL.

Comment: @Technidev gonna add an example raw file but the question is about any raw POST request not a specific one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replay the exact request you have in the file as plain HTTP you can simply use netcat:

```
cat request.txt | nc host 80
```

If you want to replay it as HTTPS instead of HTTP you can use `openssl s_client`:

```
cat request.txt | openssl s_client -connect host:443 -servername host
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat` in both examples? `<request.txt nc host 80`

Comment: @multithr3at3d: yes, it is useless use of `cat` and one could also argue that `-servername` is not needed with modern `s_client`. But, it is easier to understand this why what is going on since the input is put in front of the main command and not as `some long command with arguments < input`.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is the tool for the job.  You can view the documentation [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) as to how to pass all of the headers in the POST request that you have listed in your question.  You'll want to use the -H option to pass the header parameters that you show.

If the request is initiated from Firefox or Chrome, you can follow [these instructions](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-copyas.html) to capture a curl command that is equivalent to the POST request made by the browser.